# Horizontal Overflow refuses to work

Tags: css

I have some html/css below:

```
    #wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .completebook2 {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .completebook3 {
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    .completebook4 {
    border: 1px solid #e4e;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: chocolate;
    }
    .cover{
    background: green;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGZgzr

I cannot get horizontal scroll bars to appear no matter what. Also
I was able able to get horizontal scroll bars to appear in an earlier version of code but when I added a new node the horizontal scroll bars broke.

Also completebook2 is a node and pretty much needs to stay as well as the inner nodes of completebook2

Any ideas on this?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.completebook2`:

- remove `float:left;`
- add `display: inline-block;`

```css
        #wrapper {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
        
        .completebook2 {
        background: red;
        border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
        }
        .completebook3 {
        border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
        padding: 10px;
        }
        .completebook4 {
        border: 1px solid #e4e;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: chocolate;
        }
        .cover{
        background: green;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper">
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="completebook2">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                    <div class="completebook3">Post t</div>
                </div>
                <div class="completebook4">Post b</div>
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Nice, +1. But why does `float:left;` messes the whole thing up?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt Basically *"The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow"* ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)). If it's not in the normal flow, it isn't subject to the white-space rule (among others).

Comment: Denys great answer thanks! I was messing with it for hours. Just have to figure out how to give you credit

Comment: @JimF This is the easiest part: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work